# Could i increase speed of executing statements?

Tags: sql-server, performance, visual-studio-2010, sql-update

My function: Removes the unit in a specific row of a given Table

```
private static void removeUnits(String connectionString, String tableName, String columnID, String columnToFix)
{
    List<String> rowsToEdit = new List<String>();

    using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
    {
        using (var command = connection.CreateCommand())
        {
            command.CommandText = "SELECT " + columnID + "," + columnToFix + " FROM " + tableName;
            connection.Open();
            using (var reader = command.ExecuteReader())
            {

                var indexOfR_MEASUREDVALUEID = reader.GetOrdinal(columnID);
                var indexOfT_VALUE = reader.GetOrdinal(columnToFix);
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    var t_value = reader.GetValue(indexOfT_VALUE);
                    var t_id = reader.GetValue(indexOfR_MEASUREDVALUEID);

                    String newValue = getWithoutUnit(t_value.ToString());
                    if (newValue != null)
                    {
                        String sql = "UPDATE " + tableName + " SET " + columnToFix + "='" +
                            newValue + "' WHERE " + columnID + "='" + t_id + "';";
                        rowsToEdit.Add(sql);
                    }
                }
                connection.Close();
            }
        }

        Console.WriteLine("start writing " + rowsToEdit.Count + " entries?");
        Console.ReadLine();

        SqlCommand sqlCmd;
        sqlCmd = new SqlCommand("", connection);
        sqlCmd.Connection.Open();

        foreach (String command in rowsToEdit)
        {
            sqlCmd.CommandText = command;
            sqlCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
    }
    Console.WriteLine(rowsToEdit.Count + " commands executed");
}
```

I am using C# in Visual Studio 2010 and SQL-Server 2012.
It works fine, but executing of 200000 lines takes really long.
Is its possible to do this faster?

Comment: First, don't just add strings - use parameters. Second, I don't see why you'd need to do this as a bunch of selects and updates. Why can't you simply write a single `update` that does all the changes at once?

Comment: use parameterized queries. Also, what exactly does getWithoutUnit? Maybe you can do one update instead of doing it row by row.

Comment: And even if for some reason `getWithoutUnit` couldn't be written in SQL, you'd be better off using a table parameter to do the data. Even the amount of text in your update statements must be incredibly large for 200 000 updates - and you're just saying the same thing over, and over, and over...

Comment: @Luaan: Parameters can't be used for table names and field names.

Comment: @Guffa: Not for the table names, but they can be used for the values :) I assume this is just an internal method, so it's hopefully not needed for those. However, for the values, there's little excuse.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First try to use Parameters as already mentioned in the comments. Second, use the SqlCommand.Prepare() statement. The actual speed also depends on your machine capacities (HD Write Speed/RAM). Here is the example (you may have to edit the SqlDbTypes according to your Colum Types)

```
    private static void RemoveUnits(string connectionString, string tableName, string columnID, string columnToFix)
    {
        Dictionary<int, string> rowsToEdit = new Dictionary<int, string>();

        using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
        {
            connection.Open();

            using (SqlCommand command = connection.CreateCommand())
            {
                command.CommandText = "SELECT " + columnID + "," + columnToFix + " FROM " + tableName;

                using (var reader = command.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    var indexOfR_MEASUREDVALUEID = reader.GetOrdinal(columnID);
                    var indexOfT_VALUE = reader.GetOrdinal(columnToFix);

                    while (reader.Read())
                    {
                        string t_value = reader.GetString(indexOfT_VALUE);
                        int t_id = reader.GetInt32(indexOfR_MEASUREDVALUEID);

                        string newValue = getWithoutUnit(t_value);
                        if (newValue != null)
                        {
                            // save values in dictionary
                            rowsToEdit[t_id] = newValue;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            Console.WriteLine("start writing " + rowsToEdit.Count + " entries?");
            Console.ReadLine();

            string updateCmd = "UPDATE " + tableName + " SET " + columnToFix + "= @Value WHERE " + columnID + "= @Key;";

            using (SqlTransaction transaction = connection.BeginTransaction())
            {
                SqlCommand sqlCmd = connection.CreateCommand();
                sqlCmd.CommandText = updateCmd;
                sqlCmd.Parameters.Add("@Value", System.Data.SqlDbType.NVarChar, -1);
                sqlCmd.Parameters.Add("@Key", System.Data.SqlDbType.Int);

                // important for performance
                sqlCmd.Prepare();

                foreach (var update in rowsToEdit)
                {
                    // change values of parameters
                    sqlCmd.Parameters["@Key"].Value = update.Key;
                    sqlCmd.Parameters["@Value"].Value = update.Value;

                    // and execute it
                    sqlCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                }

                transaction.Commit();
            }
        }
        Console.WriteLine(rowsToEdit.Count + " commands executed");
    }
```

Edit: if getWithoutUnit(string) does something not very complex, you could probably do your operation with a single statement using TSQL, which comes with various string manipulation capabilities. Like `UPDATE TableName SET StringColumn = <string manipulation TSQL here>`, see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181984.aspx

Edit2: added transaction from comment hint (indeed should be faster as well), strongly typed columns

Comment: Can you update your code? If you'd put all executenonquery inside a single transaction the performance gain should be much higher than by just calling prepare...

Comment: Thx, it work's but u made two little mistakes. Adding a NVarChar-Parameter requires a size to perform sqlCmd.Prepare and @Key should better Int.

Comment: Thank your for your suggestions. From your sample code, I could not know the type of your primary key, so I kept it `object`. I fixed the NVARCHAR issue by setting -1 for MAX and added a Transaction as mentioned by Linky, which should indeed increase performance as well.

Answer (score 1):

My suggestion involves looking into parallelism:

Note: The code isn't tested, just typed it out in Notepad++

```
private static void removeUnits(String connectionString, String tableName, String  columnID, String columnToFix)
{
List<new Tuple<object, object>> rowsToEdit = new List<new Tuple<object, object>>();

using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
{
    using (var command = connection.CreateCommand())
    {
        command.CommandText = "SELECT " + columnID + "," + columnToFix + " FROM " + tableName;
        connection.Open();
        using (var reader = command.ExecuteReader())
        {
            var indexOfR_MEASUREDVALUEID = reader.GetOrdinal(columnID);
            var indexOfT_VALUE = reader.GetOrdinal(columnToFix);

            while (reader.Read())
            {
                rowsToEdit.Add(new Tuple<object, object>(reader.GetValue(indexOfT_VALUE),reader.GetValue(indexOfR_MEASUREDVALUEID)));
            }
            connection.Close();
        }
    }
}           

// Use parallelism here
Parallel.Foreach(rowsToEdit, currentRow =>
{
    String newValue = getWithoutUnit(currentRow.Value1.ToString());
    if (newValue != null)
    {
        // reopen connection
        // use parameters here, and call SP
    }
}

Console.WriteLine("start writing " + rowsToEdit.Count + " entries?");
Console.ReadLine();
```

}

Stored Proc:

```
Create StoredProcedure MySP
(
@tablename varchar(50),
@columnToFix varchar(50),
@newValue varchar(50),
@columnID varchar(50),
@tID varhcar(varchar(50)
)
As
Begin
Declare @MySQL varchar(500)
Set @MySQL = 'Update ' + @tableName + ' Set ' + @columnToFix + ' = '' + @newValue + ''' + ' Where ' + @columnID + ' = '' + @tID + '''
sp_executesql @MySQL

End
```

It's important to note that dynamic sql is generally frowned down upon.  Here's a link discussing dynamic sql (pros/cons):http://www.sommarskog.se/dynamic_sql.html

Also it's possible you may run into some locking/contention issues b/c you're hitting one table(based on the input parameters of the function).